# How can i improve my app

Tags: android

I have an app which present some beaches to the users.there is a list view with the name of every beach and when the user press on a name it opens a new activity with a photo and some text.i have created a .java class for every beach( same copy-paste code ) and a common .xml file. is there any better way to do it?for example to have all the beaches and their text in a db?

Answer (score 4):

why don't you just instance the same class but with different parameters in the constructor?
Something like this:

```
public class Beach{

    protected String name;
    protected String pathImage;

    public Beach(String name, String pathImage){
        this.name = name;
        this.pathImage = pathImage;
    }

} 


//Somewhere else in your application...
Beach beach1 = new Beach("Cancun","/images/cancun.png");
Beach beach2 = new Beach("Miami","/images/miami.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would store the beach information in a [SQLlite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database, then just create a single Beach view that knows how to display the information from the database. A problem with this is that you might want to build a simple tool to allow you to manage the information in the database so you don't have to do it through queries on the command line.

Comment: do you please have any example on that?

Comment: There aren't many good examples from my quick google search, but this one might be enough to get you going in the right direction: http://www.hdelossantos.com/2010/01/07/using-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You could ofcourse create a (abstract) superclass Beach.java and let other beaches extend that class. That way, you've got less redundant code.

```
public abstract class Beach{

    protected String name;

    public Beach(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract String getOtherInfo();

}

public class FirstBeach extends Beach{

    public FirstBeach(){
        super("FirstBeach");
    }

    public String getOtherInfo(){
        return "someInfo";
    }
}
```